# CSS Header not stretching across browser?

Tags: html, css

I'm having a really weird problem that I can't seem to figure out.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/56dVJ/2/

All I have is a simple div with the ID of 'nav', then in the css I simply have the following.

```
#nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Basically I'm trying to create a simple header that stretches across the entire page.  However, no matter what I do, there is a space around the header, like a transparent border.

I've looked at all the tutorials and posts I could find, and no one seems to have the same problem. :(

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [W3C specifies](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html) that browsers implement a default margin of 8px around the `body`. Therefore, you have to reset it to 0:

```
body { margin: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/56dVJ/4/embedded/result/) .. [Source](http://jsfiddle.net/56dVJ/4/)

The space around the `nav` is because of `margin` property in `body`, so just add this to your **CSS** :

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; /* additional for cross browsers */
}
```

Also you don't need to add `float: left` if `width: 100%`

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**This is the default margin your browser apply to your body or webpage**

to use Reset css or margin : 0;

Answer (score 0):

u need reset browser css so add this css

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,a,  abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,b, u, i, center,dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,fieldset, form, label, legend,table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,time, mark, audio, video { margin: 0;  padding: 0; border: 0;  font-size: 100%;    font: inherit;  vertical-align: baseline;}/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {    display: block;}body {  line-height: 1;}ol, ul {    list-style: none;}blockquote, q {   quotes: none;}blockquote:before, blockquote:after,q:before, q:after {   content: '';    content: none;}table {  border-collapse: collapse;  border-spacing: 0;}
```